# get exchange related properties like ExchangePattern ID and BodyType in message

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel. I'm trying to read a file from one location, making some change in the file content and sending the file to another location. I trying to get exchange related information added in the file like the following:

```
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body:
Test Message from custom processor:
Text from input file.
```

First line in the above sample is not coming. So far I wrote the following code:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="customProcessor" class="com.javacodegeeks.camel.CustomProcessor"/>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
     <from uri="file:C:\\inputdir\\" />     
     <process ref="customProcessor"/>            
     <to uri="file:C:\\outputdir\\" />
</route>
```

CustomProcessor.java:

```
public class CustomProcessor implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String msgBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    exchange.getIn().setBody("Test Message from custom processor: " + msgBody);
}
```

}

Main class:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(
            appContext, false);
    try {
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(200000);
    } finally {
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you gettting it? I am unable to understand your query, please elaborate.

Comment: I needed to print exchange properties in the file. It is coming after I have added  <to uri="log:?level=INFO" />

Comment: See the api on Exchange and Message where you can get all that information you ask about

Answer (score 1):

You can access all the properties of Camel Exchange using Exchanges' method getProperties() i.e. exchange.getProperties() which return Map, so using this you can get the information and save it into the file using your CustomProcessor Camel processor.

For more information have a look on:
http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html